# Shotwell issues in 11.10

Tags: shotwell

I had used Shotwell happily previously then updated to Natty last week.

Despite Shotwell showing on the tool bar on screen, when clicked, nothing happened, and it ignored my SD card when loaded.

I read all sorts of remedies and tried everything to no avail. When I next turned on the laptop, Ocelot was available so with nothing to loose, I upgraded again. Still no Shotwell.

Tried all the new fixes and now atleast I have the icon pictures but nothing behind it. When I ran the command to load the log file, Shotwell loaded and all my photos are present. Exited programme, and now nothing. Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong please.

Comment: type `shotwell` in terminal and tell what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. This command loads the Shotwell programme with all my photos present. This would be fine for me, but it still does not recognise my SD card.

Comment: How are you loading your SD card?  Are you going through the camera or using a reader?  What methods have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

> [image: system settings]

open systemsettings

[image]

click on the removable media icon

[image]
uncheck never prompt button

and chose shotwell in the image tab

Comment: Excellent thanks. My SD card reads now which is great and all photos are present. Still nothing behind the icon when it is clicked.

Comment: Which icon?thumbnail of images?

Comment: This problem has self corrected now! I had loaded a number of other files from "things to do after you load ubunutu" and trying to get a screen saver to work. By chance I touched the Shotwell icon and away it went. No idea what did the trick but happy anyway. Thanks for help along the way.

Comment: Didnt got it :(,which icon? You mean shotwell icon in the dash?

Comment: Any way if problem is solved ,post it as answer ,else put tick mark on the existing answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the official ppa for shotwell

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yorba/ppa
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install shotwell

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, I had tried that several times and repeated it after the above suggestions, but still nothing behind the icon.